# Errores al clonar mi repositorio 'error: invalid path'

Tags: git, rutas

tengo un error al clonar mi repositorio, mi repositorio a clonar se llama *ProgrammingProject*, pero al clonarlo no se evidencia ningún archivo y al final del comando aparece el *`error: invalid path 'C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Jorge Alza\ProgrammingDegreeProj ect\sample_1.txt'`*. Esta ruta es de otro repositorio que me tocó eliminar para poderlo reemplazarlo con este nuevo que tengo ahora. He mirado en stackoverflow en inglés pero no me ha funcionado nada.

Agradezco que me puedan ayudar, es para mi proyecto de grado de la universidad, muchas gracias

muchas gracias. Esto sale:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Jorgealza9206/ProgrammingProject.git 
Cloning into 'ProgrammingProject'... 
remote: Enumerating objects: 130, done. 
remote: Counting objects: 100% (130/130), done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (96/96), done. 
remote: Total 130 (delta 24), reused 130 (delta 24), pack-reused 0 
Receiving objects: 100% (130/130), 13.75 MiB | 2.21 MiB/s, done. 
Resolving deltas: 100% (24/24), done. 
error: invalid path 'C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Jorge Alza\ProgrammingDegreeProj ect\sample_1.txt' 
fatal: unable to checkout working tree warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. 
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Agradezco su ayuda, ya lo he clonado en varias partes y sigue igual.

Cuando intento hacer un nuevo checkout a la rama principal este es el mensaje que sale:

```
Alex@DESKTOP-V42T3BM MINGW64 /d/Mi unidad/ProgrammingProject (master) $ git checkout master
error: invalid path 'C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Jorge Alza\ProgrammingDegreeProj ect\sample_1.txt'
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Podrias colocar el comando completo y su salida en la pregunta **como texto**? Si no lo sabes formatear, no importa. Ponlo y los editores (de pronto yo) lo arreglamos para que se vea de forma apropiada (y luego puedes entrar a editar y ver lo que hicimos para que lo puedas repetir en otras ocasiones).

Comment: Así hayas borrado el repositorio, posiblemente sigue ahí la carpeta oculta .git con info del repositorio que borraste. Clónalo en otra carpeta

Comment: podes comentar que procedimiento usas para clonarlo además desde que tipo de repositorio y que editor usas

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, ya edité la pregunta

Comment: El clonado es correcto y luego falla el checkout. Durante el checkout se intenta referenciar un fichero que no existe, y que encima es de otra carpeta. Sospecho que lo que ocurre es que dentro del repo tienes un enlace simbólico a otra carpeta exterior al repo. Habría que mirar qué tienes realmente en github.

Comment: Puedes colocar la salida de este comando en la pregunta: `git ls-tree -r master | grep sample_1.txt`?

Comment: Hola, buen día, muchas gracias, ejecuto el comando y me sale esto: `Alex@DESKTOP-V42T3BM MINGW64 /d/Mi unidad/ProgrammingProject (master)
$ git ls-tree -r master | grep sample_1.txt
100644 blob f708ae17e2c9b8f0a65f7c8e61a429e05cc4d819    "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\Jorge Alza\\ProgrammingDegreeProject\\sample_1.txt"
100644 blob dea3cecd4ca6a68988ea61729d47fd658309e82d    sample_1.txt` te agradezco si puedes ver algo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que creo que está sucediendo es que los nombres de los archivos son inválidos en Windows. Lo que se me ocurre que sucedió es que creaste un archivo (por lo menos) con ese **nombre** en Linux, que como tiene backslashes, supongo que es valido en Linux.... pero en windous pues no puedes tenerlos y por eso falla el checkout (aunque la clonación se hizo sin problemas).

Aquí está una prueba de mi teoría (corriendo en linux):

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ ls
$ echo hola mundo > hola.txt
$ echo como windows > 'C:\directorio\archivo.txt'
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 XXX XXX 13 mrt 27 11:57 'C:\directorio\archivo.txt'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 XXX XXX 11 mrt 27 11:56  hola.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'una version'
[master (root-commit) 116da74] una version
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 "C:\\directorio\\archivo.txt"
 create mode 100644 hola.txt
$ git ls-tree -r @
100644 blob e2798ac2b26e944f68c138ce3fbc100681782dad    "C:\\directorio\\archivo.txt"
100644 blob 24db42bb7b999597a72801da70efd5876059bc0b    hola.txt
$ git cat-file -p @^{tree}
100644 blob e2798ac2b26e944f68c138ce3fbc100681782dad    "C:\\directorio\\archivo.txt"
100644 blob 24db42bb7b999597a72801da70efd5876059bc0b    hola.txt
```

Como se puede ver, tengo 2 archivos creados en el proyecto y funciona de perlas en linux. Pero si tratas de hacerle checkout a eso en windows, es **obvio** que windows no va a aceptar el archivo que se llama `C:\XXX`.

**Nota al margen**: El `git cat-file -p` lo hice para verificar que no hay subdirectorios en el proyecto. Son 2 archivos en la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ese archivo no sé donde lo generé si fue en Linux o en Windows, puesto que manejo el repositorio en ambos sistemas operativos. Pero lo más extraño, es que borro el archivo, no se soluciona, borro el repositorio y creo uno nuevo sin el archivo en cuestión, pero no se soluciona, y la verdad ya no sé como hacer para arreglar ese problema. En Linux, si funciona perfectamente

Comment: Creo que lo que puedes intentar hacer es simplemente cambiarle el nombre a ese archivo (y otros con el mismo problema) en Linux a nombres _"normales"_ de tal forma que al hacer checkout en Windows no haya problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, ya pude corregir mi error, no me habia dado cuenta que la ruta especificada 'C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Jorge Alza\ProgrammingDegreeProj ect\sample_1.txt' era un archivo que estaba dentro del repositorio en GitHub, aunque lo habia eliminado, no sé porque quedó creado, aunque estoy manejando GNURadio probablemente lo creó de manera automática sin que me diera cuenta. Pero ya todo solucionado. A ustedes muchas gracias, comunidad